# Accepting File Name as a Parameter for shell script output

Tags: shell, unix, parameters

I'm currently trying to create a shell script in unix that will output basic information (Time, date, etc) into the file name specified by the person running the script.

My script name is /snapshot.sh

Basically I want to be able to type ./snapshot whateveryouwanttonamethefile.txt and have it create the text file with that information. I'm pretty lost right now and can't seem to find a solution.

I have the script written, I just need to be able to redirect it to the text file.

Any help or hints would be awesome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use the `date` command, which writes to stdout the current time and date. From your question, I don't see at what point in writing your script you are stuck. Post what you have so far, and then ask a concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect output(stdout and/or stderr) you don't need to add any special code. You can use facility provide by shell.

Below are some ways to do it.

```
# redirect stdout of scirpt to new file.txt. truncate if file already exists.
bash scrip.sh > file.txt

# redirect stdout of scirpt to file.txt. Append if file already exists.
bash scrip.sh >> file.txt

# redirect stdout and stderr of scirpt to new file.txt. truncate if file already exists.
bash script.sh > file.txt 2>&1
```